# <Input type='file'/> и Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge

Имеется компонент, отвечающий за выбор файлов. Вот часть кода:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.files);
    e.target.value = "";
    //e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

render() {
    return(
        <div className={styles.button_tpfile_wrapper}>
            <div className={styles.button_tpfile_button}>
                <label className={styles.button_tpfile_label}>
                  <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} accept={this.props.filter} multiple={this.props.multiple ? "multiple" : ''} required={this.props.required ? "required" : ''} disabled={!this.props.enabled ? 'disabled' : ''} />
                  {super.render()}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`super.render()` возвращает `button`.

Этот компонент работает на Chrome, Mozilla и т.п., однако в Microsoft Edge есть некоторые проблемы, а именно: после нажатия по нужному месту открывается окно выбора файлов, и в дальнейшем это окно почти невозможно закрыть. То есть я выбираю файл, выбранный файл отображается в нужном компоненте, и тут же открывается окно выбора файла. При нажатии на кнопки отмены и закрытия всё также. Окно закрывается на доли секунды, а потом снова открывается.

В чём проблема? Есть какие то особенности в Edge? Я эти особенности не смог найти. `input` всего лишь скрыт, т.е. `opacity = 0`

**Обновление**

Нашёл вот это: [File selection...](https://github.com/jkuri/ngx-uploader/issues/28), но я пока не могу понять, как это решить.

Comment: Закрывай окно с клавиатуры нажатием Enter или Esc,

Comment: И вообще, сделай [mcve].

Comment: @Qwertiy Я после двух-трех минут после обновления решил проблему.